# PHP: SVG to PNG conversion results in wrong image

Tags: php, image, svg, imagemagick, png

I have an SVG image which is generated by a wordpress plugin.
I want to convert it to PNG for further actions.

The plugin can do this successfully via JS. The Result is this image:
[image]

When I use imagick to convert the SVG to png, I get this as a result:
[image]

The SVG code looks like this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-zoom="11.81102361" height="290" width="210" data-main="1">
<svg y="62" x="17" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" preserveAspectRatio="none" width="178" height="133"><g><image x="0" y="0" width="178" preserveAspectRatio="none" height="133" xlink:href="[BASE64 IMAGE CODE]"/></g></svg>
</svg>
```

Full version here: https://pastebin.com/vzn7BP2d

I am using this code for the conversion:

```
$svg = file_get_contents('front-test.svg');

$im = new Imagick();
$im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$im->setResolution(300, 300); // for 300 DPI example
$im->readImageBlob('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>'.$svg);

$im->setImageFormat("png24");
//$im->resizeImage(250, 250, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1);

$im->writeImage('front-test.png');
$im->clear();
$im->destroy();
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can solve this?
It is neccessary that the image is positioned correctly on the "canvas" because it is a print template for t-shirts and needs be exact.

Comment: You did not provide the linked image for us to be able to test. But your issue is likely which SVG renderer that ImageMagick is using. ImageMagick can use its own internal MSVG/XML render, which is like what you are using and which is not very good. Then you could install the RSVG delegate, which is better. But the best solution is to install Inkscape and ImageMagick will use that automatically. It is the best choice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the full version of the svg in my post. I am on a shared host, which does not support the recommended add-ons

Comment: Are you sure you cannot have them install Inkscape? It is not a delegate that needs to be installed with ImageMagick.

Comment: I tested using ImageMagick with each of MSVG, RSVG and Inkscape to convert to PNG. MSVG gave the same results as you got. RSVG gave a blank image. Inkscape works fine.

Comment: If you cannot use Inkscape, then perhaps post a bug report regarding MSVG to the bugs forum at https://imagemagick.org/discourse-server/

Comment: I'll try to ask my hoster. But I would like to provide that plugins to other people. Not everybody would be able to install additional software. I'll check the forum and may report a bug. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 1):

The SVG file you have is not really a vector image. It is only a PNG wrapped in a SVG. That makes it trivial to get the image: read the data url that makes up the image, decode it and write the result to a file. No ImageMagick required, only gd.

```
$svg = simplexml_load_file('front-test.svg');
$data_url = $svg->svg->g->image['xlink:href'];
$encoded = $data_url.explode(',')[1];
$data = base64_decode($encoded);
$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
imagepng($im, 'front-test.png');
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. My example is very simplified. The SVG can be very complex with different types of nodes. Since I need the pictures positioned on the underlaying canvas, your code would just extract the image.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to fmw42 for giving suggestions about different renderers. After some research for this issue, I found that even imagemagick recommends to use another renderer and closed this issue with `won't fix`:

> We recommend the libRSVG delegate library or inkscape delegate program as the preferred SVG renderer. The internal renderer is less robust and likely will never support all of the SVG standard.

Source: https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/issues/335

To solve this, I tried different online converters to see, if they also have this problem. Most of them gave me just an empty canvas, others had the same outcome as my 2nd picture in my question.

I stopped searching for converters after I found https://convertio.co/de/ 
They are able to give me the correct output image. They have an API which can be used for 25 conversion minutes for free daily: https://developers.convertio.co/

This was the only soultion for my case, since I wanted the project to be flexible, since some users may won't be able to install inkscape on their server.